# Question timeline is showing a question got on the HNQ more than once. (A very hot question?)

Tags: bug, specific-question, hot-network-questions

I saw this ([Can a symbol carry different meanings throughout a film or a book?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/62628/can-a-symbol-carry-different-meanings-throughout-a-film-or-a-book)) question show up in my hot network questions feeds. I immediately went to the timeline and saw this:

[image]

From the screenshot you can see the timeline is reporting it got on the HNQ list more than once.

How did this happen?

Comment: Using my skills of Meta Stack Exchange  searching (After posting this question.) I've just discovered it's not a new case...

Comment: Nice catch. I'm pretty sure the relevant MSE duplicate is [How hot? Double hot (bug resurfaced?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362207/323179)